# Kubernetes pods can't ping each other using ClusterIP

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to ping the kube-dns service from a dnstools pod using the cluster IP assigned to the kube-dns service. The ping request times out. From the same dnstools pod, I tried to curl the kube-dns service using the exposed port,  but that timed out as well.

Following is the output of `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide`

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP             NODE          NOMINATED NODE
default         pod/busybox                               1/1     Running   62         2d14h   192.168.1.37   kubenode      <none>
default         pod/dnstools                              1/1     Running   0          2d13h   192.168.1.45   kubenode      <none>
default         pod/nginx-deploy-7c45b84548-ckqzb         1/1     Running   0          6d11h   192.168.1.5    kubenode      <none>
default         pod/nginx-deploy-7c45b84548-vl4kh         1/1     Running   0          6d11h   192.168.1.4    kubenode      <none>
dmi             pod/elastic-deploy-5d7c85b8c-btptq        1/1     Running   0          2d14h   192.168.1.39   kubenode      <none>
kube-system     pod/calico-node-68lc7                     2/2     Running   0          6d11h   10.62.194.5    kubenode      <none>
kube-system     pod/calico-node-9c2jz                     2/2     Running   0          6d12h   10.62.194.4    kubemaster    <none>
kube-system     pod/coredns-5c98db65d4-5nprd              1/1     Running   0          6d12h   192.168.0.2    kubemaster    <none>
kube-system     pod/coredns-5c98db65d4-5vw95              1/1     Running   0          6d12h   192.168.0.3    kubemaster    <none>
kube-system     pod/etcd-kubemaster                       1/1     Running   0          6d12h   10.62.194.4    kubemaster    <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-apiserver-kubemaster             1/1     Running   0          6d12h   10.62.194.4    kubemaster    <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-controller-manager-kubemaster    1/1     Running   1          6d12h   10.62.194.4    kubemaster    <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-9hcgv                      1/1     Running   0          6d11h   10.62.194.5    kubenode      <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-bxw9s                      1/1     Running   0          6d12h   10.62.194.4    kubemaster    <none>
kube-system     pod/kube-scheduler-kubemaster             1/1     Running   1          6d12h   10.62.194.4    kubemaster    <none>
kube-system     pod/tiller-deploy-767d9b9584-5k95j        1/1     Running   0          3d9h    192.168.1.8    kubenode      <none>
nginx-ingress   pod/nginx-ingress-66wts                   1/1     Running   0          5d17h   192.168.1.6    kubenode      <none>
```

In the above output, why do some pods have an IP assigned in the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet whereas others have an IP that is equal to the IP address of my node/master? (10.62.194.4 is the IP of my master, 10.62.194.5 is the IP of my node)

This is the `config.yml` I used to initialize the cluster using `kubeadm init --config=config.yml`

```
apiServer:
certSANs:
- 10.62.194.4
extraArgs:
    authorization-mode: Node,RBAC
timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: dev-cluster
controllerManager: {}
dns:
type: CoreDNS
etcd:
local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
imageRepository: k8s.gcr.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: v1.15.1
networking:
dnsDomain: cluster.local
podSubnet: 192.168.0.0/16
serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: {}
```

Result of `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                    TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE     SELECTOR
default       service/kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                  6d12h   <none>
default       service/nginx-deploy    ClusterIP   10.97.5.194     <none>        80/TCP                   5d17h   run=nginx
dmi           service/elasticsearch   ClusterIP   10.107.84.159   <none>        9200/TCP,9300/TCP        2d14h   app=dmi,component=elasticse
dmi           service/metric-server   ClusterIP   10.106.117.2    <none>        8098/TCP                 2d14h   app=dmi,component=metric-se
kube-system   service/calico-typha    ClusterIP   10.97.201.232   <none>        5473/TCP                 6d12h   k8s-app=calico-typha
kube-system   service/kube-dns        ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   6d12h   k8s-app=kube-dns
kube-system   service/tiller-deploy   ClusterIP   10.98.133.94    <none>        44134/TCP                3d9h    app=helm,name=tiller
```

The command I ran was `kubectl exec -ti dnstools -- curl 10.96.0.10:53`

EDIT:

I raised this question because I got this error when trying to resolve service names from within the cluster. I was under the impression that I got this error because I cannot ping the DNS server from a pod.

Output of `kubectl exec -ti dnstools -- nslookup kubernetes.default`

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

Output of `kubectl exec dnstools cat /etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local reddog.microsoft.com
options ndots:5
```

Result of `kubectl get ep kube-dns --namespace=kube-system`

```
NAME       ENDPOINTS                                                  AGE
kube-dns   192.168.0.2:53,192.168.0.3:53,192.168.0.2:53 + 3 more...   6d13h
```

EDIT:
Ping-ing the CoreDNS pod directly using its Pod IP times out as well:

```
/ # ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 192.168.0.2 ping statistics ---
24 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

EDIT:
I think something has gone wrong when I was setting up the cluster. Below are the steps I took when setting up the cluster:

1. Edit host files on master and worker to include the IP's and hostnames of the nodes
2. Disabled swap using `swapoff -a` and disabled swap permanantly by editing `/etc/fstab`
3. Install docker prerequisites using `apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common -y`
4. Added Docker GPG key using `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -`
5. Added Docker repo using `add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"`
6. Install Docker using `apt-get update -y; -get install docker-ce -y`
7. Install Kubernetes prerequisites using `curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -`
8. Added Kubernetes repo using `echo 'deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list`
9. Update repo and install Kubernetes components using `apt-get update -y; apt-get install kubelet kubeadm kubectl -y`

Configure master node:

1. `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.62.194.4 --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=10.62.194.4  --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16`
2. Copy Kube config to `$HOME`: `mkdir -p $HOME/.kube; sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config; sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config`
3. Installed Calico using `kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/rbac-kdd.yaml; kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.1/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml`

On node:
On the node I did the `kubeadm join` command using the command printed out from `kubeadm token create --print-join-command` on the master

Comment: `kubectl exec dnstools cat /etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: Added the result of requested command as an edit. Please check

Comment: check endpoint is exposed or not ? `kubectl get ep kube-dns --namespace=kube-system`

Comment: Yes they seemed to be exposed. Please check the new update

Comment: @user3583252, Any solution found ? Facing similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

The kubernetes system pods get assigned the host ip since they provide low level services that are not dependant on an overlay network (or in case of calico even provide the overlay network). They have the ip of the node where they run.

A common pod uses the overlay network and gets assigned an ip from the calico range, not from the metal node they run on.

You can't access DNS (port 53) with HTTP using curl. You can use `dig` to query a DNS resolver.
A service IP is not reachable by ping since it is a virtual IP just used as a routing handle for the iptables rules setup by kube-proxy, therefore a TCP connection works, but ICMP not.
You can ping a pod IP though, since it is assigned from the overlay network.

Comment: When I try to query the DNS resolver, I get an error which can be seen in the edit to my question. Please check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check on the same `namespace`

Currently, you are in `default` namespace and `curl` to other `kube-system` namespace.

You should check in the same namespace, I think it works.

[image]

Comment: How do you specify a namespace when curl-ing an IP address? Also, if I ping the coredns pod directly using its Pod IP (192.168.0.2), that times out as well

Comment: you can check `kubectl exec -ti dnstools -- curl 10.97.5.194:80`

Comment: `ping` time out because pods deny `ping` package, which `command` did you check DNS query ?

Comment: I used the command specified on this page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/ which is `kubectl exec -ti dnstools -- nslookup kubernetes.default`

Comment: how's it going ?

Comment: I'm still stuck here unfortunately.. Do you have any idea? Been stuck on this issue since last Friday night

Comment: did you re-deploy pods as well as svc ?

Comment: Yep. Only thing I didnt do is to take down the entire cluster and bring it back up. I can do that but I am not sure where I went wrong the first time

Comment: I'll update my question to list the steps I took to install the Kube cluster. Let me know if anything seems wrong.

Comment: I edited the question to include the steps I took to set up K8s.. Please check

Comment: For me, I can nslookup as picture which is attached

Answer (score 0):

On some cases the local host that Elasticsearch publishes is not routable/accessible from other hosts. On these cases you will have to configure `network.publish_host` in the yml config file, in order for Elasticsearch to use and publish the right address.

Try configuring network.publish_host to the right public address.

See more here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings

Answer (score 0):

note that control plane components like api server, etcd that runs on master node are bound to host network. and hence you see the ip address of the master server.

On the other hand, the apps that you deployed are going to get the ips from the pod subnet range. those vary from cluster node ip's

Try below steps to test dns working or not

deploy nginx.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    name: web
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: nginx
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  serviceName: "nginx"
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: k8s.gcr.io/nginx-slim:0.8
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: web
        volumeMounts:
        - name: www
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      volumes:
      - name: www
        emptyDir:
```

```
kuebctl create -f nginx.yaml

master $ kubectl get po
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-0     1/1       Running   0          1m
web-1     1/1       Running   0          1m

master $ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   35m
nginx        ClusterIP   None         <none>        80/TCP    2m

master $ kubectl run -i --tty --image busybox:1.28 dns-test --restart=Never --rm
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup nginx
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      nginx
Address 1: 10.40.0.1 web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 10.40.0.2 web-1.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
/ #


/ # nslookup web-0.nginx
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      web-0.nginx
Address 1: 10.40.0.1 web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local


/ # nslookup web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 1: 10.40.0.1 web-0.nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: Got it. Could you please check the edit to my question.. Service names are not being resolved within the cluster because a pod cannot reach the DNS service

Comment: Hi.. I did what you said. The nslookup request times out because it cannot reach the DNS server/pod. Do you have any idea? Thanks